# How to solve this second order linear pde?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I have the following pde for $f(t,x,y)$:

$a x^2 f_{xx} + bxf_x + f_t - bxy + c = 0$ subject to $f(T,x,y)=0$ for all positive $x,y$, where  $a,b$ and $c$ are constants.

The equation seems to be simple enough (second order linear pde, with polynomial coeficients of simple form and low degree) but non of the standard methods I now seems to work out well.

Any ideas? Can we guarantee at least that there is existence and uniqueness of a regular solution?

Comment: What form do you want the solution on? This will probably be very easily expressed if you accept a solution in terms of a multidimensional power series as both multiplication with x and y as well as differentiation just permute which monomials' coefficient it affects (and multiply with constants).

Comment: @mathreadler Any form. Any solution would do. I was under the same impression so I tried a couple of polynomials but somehow I couldn't get coefficients that work out. Are you saying the solution won't be unique?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can get ridd of the source term by defining

$$f(x,y,z,t) = xy - ct + u(x,y,z,t)\tag{1}$$

so that the PDE for $u$ becomes

$$ax^2u_{xx} + bx u_x + u_t = 0\tag{2}$$

We can then perform a change of variables $z = \log(x)$ to get

$$au_{zz} + (b-a) u_z + u_t = 0\tag{3}$$

which is linear second order homogenous PDE with constant coefficients and you can for example use separation of variables to solve it. Note that the last step is not really needed if you intend to use separation of variables as this can be applied directly to $(2)$ (but you might need to perform a similar change variables on the resulting ODE to solve it).

Comment: brilliant solution!! thank you!! I only changed one thing: in the first step, to get rid of the source term I used $+c(T-t)$ instead of $-ct$. Everything works in the same way but the new boundary condition gets simpler and when you use separation of variables in the end you get a solution on the spot, without going to series or even linear combinations.

Comment: This log change happens to work very nicely here, but would not work for exponents other than the number of differentiations for example terms $bx^3f_x$, but my approach would.

Comment: @mathreadler Thank you for the insight on your method. I was wondering how did you come up with that change of variable. Now I  understand it better! As for the eradication of the source term was it just trial and error or do you have a general idea there as well?

Comment: @mathreadler Sorry I confused you with Winther in the last comment. Thank you for your help as well. I failed to say I was looking for an analytical solution

Comment: @webbster Yes, it's basically guesswork. The simple form of the source is an indication that it *could* work. For finding it there are some rough guidelines one can use. If the source is separable $S(x,t) = g(x) + h(t)$ then you can always solve (if possible) $ax^2f^{\rm p}_{xx} + bxf^{\rm p}_x = g(x)$ and $f_t^{\rm p} = h(t)$ to find a particular solution that will kill the source. When you have cross-terms, say $(xy)^n$ or $\sin(x/t)$, then it becomes much harder and this will often not work. The same is the case if the equation is non-linear in $f$.

Comment: @webbster For the change of variables: whenever I see terms on the form $x^n \frac{d^n f}{dx^n}$ that is an indication that $\log(x)$ is a thing to try as $x\frac{d}{dx} =  \frac{d}{d\log x} \implies$ such terms can be written as a linear combination of terms $\left(\frac{d}{d\log(x)}\right)^k$.

Comment: @Winther Brilliant!! Thanks again for your solution and explanations!

Answer (score 1):

Let us write f as a multivariate polynomial or power series

$$f(t,x,y) = \sum_{{k,l,m}\in{\mathbb N}^3}c_{klm}x^ky^lt^m$$
The partial differential operators will perform (sum omitted): 
$$\frac{\partial f} {\partial x} = kc_{klm}x^{k-1}y^lt^m \hspace{1cm} \frac{\partial f} {\partial y} = lc_{klm}x^{k}y^{l-1}t^m \hspace{1cm}\frac{\partial f} {\partial t} = mc_{klm}x^{k}y^lt^{m-1}$$

Multiplication with a monomial in x : $x^n$ will give $c_{klm}x^{k+n}y^lt^m$, so all terms will together create a linear equations system for the coefficients $c_{klm}$.

Now remains the boundary conditions. I will assume that $T$ is a constant value for $t$. Then we see that $$f(T,x,y) = \sum_{k,l,m\in\mathbb N^3}c_{klm}x^ky^lT^m = \sum_{k,l,m\in\mathbb N^3}c_{klm}T^mx^ky^l$$ And we see that setting equal to zero and treating $T^m$ as constants just gives us one more set of linear equations involving all terms with $x^ky^lt^0$.

Now the problem that remains is the book-keeping to build this equation system. How you would want to do this in practice depends on what computer language(s) you are familiar with.

For existance I suppose we can analyze the rank of our equation system for a finite approximation. There will definitely exist at least some norm-minimizing solution for any approximation of finite dimensions due to the existence of pseudo-inverse and as the space of functions is so that each new is linearly independent from the others... However it is possible that we find *infinite* number of solutions and in that case what we need to do is to introduce some kind of a **regularizer** to encourage *more interesting* solutions and/or *simpler representation* over others.

---

**EDIT**
Just to show the reasonability (response to Winther's comment):

If we disregard the boundary condition for a second we can find the (trivial) solution $f = bxy - ct$ by hand. If we exchange the $-bxy$ term to $-bxy^k$ still solves it (still trivial since $f_{xx}$ zero, right?). Here is an example with $-bxy^6$,$a=4$,$b=1$, $c=10$.

```
 sparse(reshape(v_0,[9,9,9])(:,:,1))
        (2, 7) ->  1.00000
 sparse(reshape(v_0,[9,9,9])(:,:,2))
        (1, 1) -> -10.0000
```

So the indexes are exponents+1 ( Languages like Matlab and Octave start indexing at 1 instead of 0 ). So (2,7) first line is the coefficient for $x^1y^6t^0$ and the second line is for $x^0y^0t^1$. I don't have any other "ground truth" to compare to, so I guess this will have to do so far. As you can see the candidate polynomial includes coefficients for all up to exponents 8 for all k,l,m. A small regularizer pushes all of the rest coefficients to $0$ or close to the machine constant $10^{-15}$ for our example.

[image]

Comment: What is gained by splitting it into a polynomial series if solving it numerically? This significantly
complicates things imo - there are much simpler and better methods for this. For an analytical solution this method does work in some cases (like when the solution happens to be a polynomial), however it tends to fail dramatically when the solution is oscillating.

Comment: One could for example try and identify the series or parts of the series with well known Taylor expansions. One could add arbitrary localized boundary conditions and other monomial terms like $-bxy$ directly affect exactly one position in the equation system.

Comment: Let me rephrase the question. I agree that this is one method one *could* try. However you seem to suggest that this is the way OP should go to solve the problem at hand. I can’t see that this is a good suggestion - it looks like a nightmare implementing this and my intuition tells me that this will very likely fail. What is wrong by using the much simpler method of discretising on a grid and propagating the solution using the PDE from the boundary? What am I missing here?